# Empty TH2F histogram in Root

Tags: c++, root-framework

I'm trying to plot a 2-dimensional from a root file but for some reason instead of a nice plot I get a blank Canvas with 918 entries, mean x=0, mean y=47 and both of the standard deviations equal to 0. I have no idea why did it happen and apparently the problem is with the last line `h1->Fill(xk,yk);`, because the cout just before it works. Could you help me figure it out?

Here is my full code:

```
{
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

TFile f1("data1.root");
TFile f2("data2.root");

TTreeReader reader("T1", &f1);
TTreeReaderValue<Double_t> X(reader, "X"); 
TTreeReaderValue<Double_t> Y(reader, "Y");

TH2F* h1=new TH2F("h1"," ",10000,0,900,0,70);

vector<vector<Double_t>>v1;

while (reader.Next()) {
    //cout<<*X<<" "<<*Y<<endl;
    vector<Double_t>i;
    i.push_back(*X);
    i.push_back(*Y);
    v1.push_back(i);
}

for (int k=0;k<918;k++)
    {
        Double_t xk=v1[k][0];
        Double_t yk=v1[k][1];
        cout<<xk<<" "<<yk<<endl;
        h1->Fill(xk,yk);
    }

h1->Draw();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're calling a wrong constructor in

```cpp
TH2F* h1=new TH2F("h1"," ",10000,0,900,0,70);
```

The constructors of TH2F from [here](https://root.cern/doc/v618/classTH2F.html#a7754fef4bcd5079d8207417a7659629e) take 6 numeric arguments (3 for the x axis and 3 for the y axis) or pointers to arrays and you're providing 5.

Inspecting the histogram you create:

```cpp
root [2] h->GetXaxis()->GetNbins()
(int) 10000
root [3] h->GetYaxis()->GetNbins()
(int) 900

root [6] h->GetXaxis()->GetBinLowEdge(1)
(double) 0.0000000


root [10] h->GetYaxis()->GetBinLowEdge(1)
(double) 0.0000000
root [11] h->GetYaxis()->GetBinUpEdge(900)
(double) 70.000000

root [13] h->GetXaxis()->GetBinUpEdge(10000)
(double) 1.0000000
```

it looks like the overload resolution picked the instantiation of the x-axis different from what you intended. I suspect (from the numbers you provided) you missed the number of bins for the y-axis:

```cpp
TH2F* h1=new TH2F("h1"," ",10000,0,900,10000,0,70);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now.
I have got one new problem. I created a second histogram with the same method and now I want to subtract them. So i tried doing it like that:
TH2F*hs=(TH2F*)h1->Clone("hs");
hs->Add(h2,-1);

c.cd(3);
hs->Draw();

Unfortunately, it gave me an empty histogram. To see what's going on I tried to add them with 1 instead of -1 and then I got two superimposed histograms on one canvas, not one with added values from both of them. Both of the histogram have the same x values and different y. Could you help me with that?

Comment: 1) with the code you posted, yes you should get an empty histogram. `Clone` copies structure and content. so Clone followed subtraction should end up with an empty histogram. 2) superimposition doesn't work with 2D histograms (iirc) I also have a hard time imagining how that's supposed to look. are you sure you want 2D histograms and not plot some y as function of x? in that case 1D histograms are what you're looking for. 3) Subtraction can be done with `-` https://root.cern/doc/v618/classTH1F.html#aac67adc36ae6898718b7e91616f5f803 which is probably more readable?

Comment: oh ok thanks
I somehow did what I wanted with for loops xd

Comment: ok, if you mean for loops over bins, be aware that the builtin methods (as annoying as they may seem) do a lot of things right that one may not think about at first (overflow/underflow bins, the sum-of-weights-squared structure, …). That might not be relevant for what you're working on now but it might be worth in the long run to learn how to use them correctly rather than learning how to bodge around them.